# Defining labels in Tkinter using values from another list

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop, tkinter, label

Well, I was trying to define Labels from another list that contain hours but no sucess.

```
        def loop_label():
        for item in Acd_horario:
            Acd_horario[item] = Label(framerajada, text=[Acd_horario[item]], 
                                      font=font_acd, bg=bg_acd, fg=fg_acd, bd=bd_acd,
                                      relief=relief_acd)

    loop_label()
```

I tried like above, but no sucess. The other list I`m using is from another class, with gets the hour of another list of objects from the class itself:

```
  Acd_lista = [Acd_0715, Acd_0745, Acd_0815, Acd_0845, Acd_0915, Acd_0945, 
               Acd_1015, Acd_1045, Acd_1115, Acd_1145,
               Acd_1215, Acd_1245, Acd_1315, Acd_1345, Acd_1415, Acd_1445, 
               Acd_1515, Acd_1545, Acd_1615, Acd_1645,
               Acd_1715, Acd_1745, Acd_1815, Acd_1845, Acd_1915, Acd_1945, 
               Acd_2015]

  Acd_horario = [i.horario for i in Acd_lista]
```

Maybe is my logic that isn't right. Anyone has any idea on this?

The error I receive is: `TypeError list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Comment: What does “no success” mean? Does the program crash? Does it throw errors? Does it create the wrong number of labels? Something else’s?

Comment: Oh I forgot about that. It's in the final of the question the error I got. It crashes and doesn't open the GUI.

Comment: You can create the labels by `labelList = [Label(framerajada, text=item, ...) for item in Acd_horario]`.